# What's the function used by ggplot2::scale_size exp?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I build a ggplot where I pass word sizes say e.g.

```
textSizes <- c(4.0000000,3.1148256,3.0130814,2.8604651,2.5247093,2.3110465,2.0872093,1.8633721,1.8633721,1.6497093,1.6090116,1.6090116,1.5886628,1.5683140,1.3037791,1.2936047,1.2122093,1.1816860,1.1715116,1.1613372,1.1511628,1.1409884,1.0392442,1.0188953,0.9578488,0.8561047,0.7950581,0.7848837,0.7441860,0.7441860,0.5508721)
textSizes
```

Assuming p is my plot I use `scale_size` like this:

```
p <- p + ggplot2::scale_size(range = c(1.7,15), trans='exp', guide = FALSE)
```

i.e. I want an exponential re-scaling of the text sizes within the interval 1.7 and 15. To check what ggplot is computing I do:

```
pg <- ggplot_build(p)
pg
```

and I see that the resulting sizes that ggplot computes are:

```
pg[[1]][[1]]$size
 [1] 15.000000 10.041629  9.592390  8.956145  7.698310  6.985947  6.301446  5.670228  5.670228  5.107868  5.004377  5.004377  4.953005
[14]  4.901867  4.253383  4.228834  4.032666  3.959037  3.934464  3.909870  3.885253  3.860608  3.611824  3.561322  3.407508  3.139436
[27]  2.967087  2.937132  2.812636  2.812636  1.700000
```

However, I can't manually reproduce these values. I tried the following:

```
interval <- log(c(1.7, 15))
interval
[1] 0.5306283 2.7080502
start <- interval[1]
end <- interval[2]

result <- exp(start+(end-start)*((textSizes-min(textSizes))/(max(textSizes)-min(textSizes))))
result
 [1] 15.000000  8.578360  8.044689  7.305781  5.910347  5.164560  4.483986  3.893096  3.893096  3.401853  3.315564  3.315564  3.273245
[14]  3.231465  2.734465  2.716957  2.580874  2.531618  2.515410  2.499305  2.483303  2.467404  2.313903  2.284368  2.198007  2.061266
[27]  1.983339  1.970641  1.920656  1.920656  1.700000
```

Basically I do a linear scaling of the `textSizes` to the interval `log(c(1.7, 15))` so that doing `exp` will give me the desired mapping but my manually computed results don't match ggplot2's.

What is the correct function that ggplot2 is using here?

**UPDATE** I see that my initial linear mapping doesn't match ggplot2's

```
log(pg[[1]][[1]]$size)
 [1] 2.7080502 2.3067393 2.2609701 2.1923399 2.0410008 1.9439006 1.8407791 1.7352294 1.7352294 1.6307821 1.6103129 1.6103129 1.5999944
[14] 1.5896162 1.4477146 1.4419264 1.3944278 1.3760009 1.3697746 1.3635042 1.3571881 1.3508248 1.2842130 1.2701318 1.2259813 1.1440433
[27] 1.0875806 1.0774335 1.0341220 1.0341220 0.5306283
```

whereas my linear mapping gives:

```
 start+(end-start)*((textSizes-min(textSizes))/(max(textSizes)-min(textSizes)))
 [1] 2.7080502 2.1492428 2.0850121 1.9886659 1.7767045 1.6418200 1.5005124 1.3592047 1.3592047 1.2243202 1.1986279 1.1986279 1.1857818
[14] 1.1729356 1.0059357 0.9995127 0.9481280 0.9288588 0.9224357 0.9160127 0.9095896 0.9031665 0.8389358 0.8260896 0.7875512 0.7233205
[27] 0.6847820 0.6783589 0.6526666 0.6526666 0.5306283
```

and the difference gives:

```
log(pg[[1]][[1]]$size) - (start+(end-start)*((textSizes-min(textSizes))/(max(textSizes)-min(textSizes))))
 [1] 0.0000000 0.1574965 0.1759580 0.2036739 0.2642962 0.3020806 0.3402667 0.3760246 0.3760246 0.4064619 0.4116851 0.4116851 0.4142126
[14] 0.4166806 0.4417789 0.4424138 0.4462998 0.4471421 0.4473389 0.4474915 0.4475985 0.4476583 0.4452772 0.4440422 0.4384301 0.4207228
[27] 0.4027986 0.3990746 0.3814553 0.3814553 0.0000000
```

Comment: This is interesting, did you look at the [source code for scale_size](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/00ecd3670ef0f1c195bf4c6b5ada3b1895712f1c/R/scale-size.r)?

Comment: you could try `log(x + 1)` or something -- this is sometimes used when the function should return 0 (not -Inf) for x=0

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 thanks for reaching out :) yes I tried checking the ggplot2 but the code is hard to follow as there are many chained calls. I tried `log(x+1)` and it is much closer but not exactly yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK after debugging `ggplot` for a while I found the exact transformation:

```
textSizes <- c(4.0000000,3.1148256,3.0130814,2.8604651,2.5247093,2.3110465,2.0872093,1.8633721,1.8633721,1.6497093,1.6090116,1.6090116,1.5886628,1.5683140,1.3037791,1.2936047,1.2122093,1.1816860,1.1715116,1.1613372,1.1511628,1.1409884,1.0392442,1.0188953,0.9578488,0.8561047,0.7950581,0.7848837,0.7441860,0.7441860,0.5508721)
y <- exp(1)^textSizes
x <- (y-min(y))/(max(y)-min(y))
scales::rescale(x=sqrt(x), to=c(1.7,15), from=c(0, 1))
 [1] 15.000000 10.041629  9.592390  8.956145  7.698310  6.985947  6.301446  5.670228  5.670228  5.107868  5.004377
[12]  5.004377  4.953005  4.901867  4.253383  4.228835  4.032666  3.959037  3.934464  3.909870  3.885253  3.860608
[23]  3.611824  3.561322  3.407508  3.139436  2.967087  2.937132  2.812635  2.812635  1.700000
```